# How can I count the number of occurrences of each character in a string in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that takes a string as input and counts the number of times each character appears in the string. I'm having trouble figuring out how to efficiently iterate over the characters in the string and keep track of the count for each character. Can anyone suggest a good way to approach this problem in Python?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't overuse irrelevant tags. It's a Python question. You used all the other tags except the "python" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Counter class in the collections module.

```
from collections import Counter

string = "blueblack"

Counter(string)

Counter({'b': 2, 'l': 2, 'u': 1, 'e': 1, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'k': 1})

# OR

c = Counter(string)

c.items()

dict_items([('b', 2), ('l', 2), ('u', 1), ('e', 1), ('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('k', 1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged the question with the Oracle tag, I presume that Oracle *solution* might be OK for you as well, so - here's one option.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as
  3    (select 'Littlefoot' from dual),
  4  temp as
  5    -- split the string into separate characters
  6    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^\.]', 1, level) character
  7     from test
  8     connect by level <= length(col)
  9    )
 10  -- count them
 11  select character, count(*)
 12  from temp
 13  group by character;

CHARACTER                                  COUNT(*)
---------------------------------------- ----------
L                                                 1
i                                                 1
t                                                 3
l                                                 1
e                                                 1
f                                                 1
o                                                 2

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: It was an overuse of using tags. They said: "Can anyone suggest a good way to approach this problem in **Python**?"